# CodeIgniter Internal server error using HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, codeigniter-3

I have this .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The Homepage runs correctly but when i tried to click the other pages it goes to 500 Internal server error. I also changed my base_url into

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://sample.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I am using Go Daddy as a Linux Server. Is there anyone who can help me out of this one. I tried to execute the other post here but then nothing happens. If you wanted to know the live URL of the site i can give you the link. please

Sample:
Home is my Controller name and page is my function so it looks like this

```
 https://sample.com/home/page
```

But then it says an 500 Internal server error
Please check this link https://goatquest.com/ ang then go to the footer click on the other link for the sample.

I also changed the routes see the code:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['user-profile'] = 'home/user_profile';
$route['settings-and-privacy'] = 'home/user_setting';
$route['leaderboard'] = 'home/leaderboard';
$route['wall-of-fame'] = 'home/wall_of_fame';
$route['contact-us'] = 'home/contact_us';
$route['data-policy'] = 'home/data_policy';
$route['terms-of-use'] = 'home/terms_of_use';
```

I also tried to upload a clean codeigniter framework and create a controller and call it but still no luck. I`m thinking maybe because of the server? This is Web Hosting Linux in GoDaddy

Comment: show how you access your other url

Comment: This row: `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)` seems unnecessary. You're already checking if the request is or isn't a real file or folder.

Comment: You could turn in "display_errors" while debugging the issue to find the _actual_ error message. (Or preferably, if it is possible on GoDaddy, check the servers error log)

Comment: provide the link of your live URL

Comment: I already edited my post. I also post the link on the website

Comment: is home your default controller?

Comment: It seems that all controller have the same error.

Comment: yes @pradeep it is my default controller